# Issues Training CNN with Prime number input dimensions

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, max-pooling

I am currently developing a CNN model with Keras (an autoencoder). This type my inputs are of shape `(47,47,3)`, that is a 47x47 image with 3 (RGB) layers.

I have worked with some CNN's in the past, but this time my input dimensions are prime numbers (47 pixels). This I think is causing issues with my implementation, specifically when using `MaxPooling2D` and `UpSampling2D` in my model. I noticed that **some dimensions are lost when max pooling and then up sampling**.

Using `model.summary()` I can see that after passing my **`(47,47,3)`** input through a `Conv2D(24)` and MaxPooling with a `(2,2)` kernel (that is 24 filters and half the shape) I get a output shape of **`(24, 24, 24)`**.

Now, if I try to reverse that by UpSampling with a `(2,2)` kernel (double the shape) and convolving again I get a **`(48,48,3)`** shaped output. That is one extra row and column than needed.

To this I thought *"no problem, just chose a kernel size that gives you the desired 47 pixels when up sampling"*, but given that 47 is a prime number it seems to me that there is no kernel size that can do that.

**Is there any way to bypass this problem that does not involve changing my input dimensions to a non-prime?** Maybe I am missing something in my approach or maybe Keras has some feature I ignore that could help here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I advice you to use [ZeroPadding2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#zeropadding2d) and [Cropping2D](https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#cropping2d). You can pad your image asymmetrically with `0`s and obtain an even size of your image without resizing it. This should solve the problem with upsampling. Moreover - remember about setting `padding=same` in all of your convolutional layers.

**EDIT:**

Just to give you an example strategy on how to perform such operations:

1. If before pooling the size of your network is odd - zero pad it to make it even.
2. After corresponding upsample operation use cropping in order to bring back your feature map to original odd size.

Comment: Yep, padding is same, will check out what you see :) thanks

Comment: I was checking what you suggested, so should I include that layer in my model before doing each Pooling and Sampling? I suppose that the `padding` parameter should be such that the resulting size is not prime correct?

Comment: I updated my answer. Tell me if there is something you cannot understand.

Comment: Thanks, it is much clearer now. I tried what you suggested and added a one layer of paddings to make it `(49,49)`, which I can now divide with `(3,3)` kernels for example. and then Cropped it back to 47's.