# Conv2d wrong dimensions on Keras

Tags: python-3.x, keras

I'm new to Keras and I'm trying to use convolutional autoencoders for image compression.

In particular I'm compressing images which are all of dimensions (365,929). As I'm working with numpy 2D arrays for the images, I add a dimension to make them tensors.

When feeding the network with the images with this code:

```
X,X_test=train_test_split(images,test_size=0.1)
# Adds 1D to each matrix, so to have a tensor.
X=np.array([np.expand_dims(i,axis=2) for i in X]) 
# X is (1036, 365, 929, 1) now
X_test=np.array([np.expand_dims(i,axis=2) for i in X_test])
inputs = Input(shape=(365, 929, 1))
h = Conv2D(4,(3,3),activation='relu',padding="same")(inputs)
encoded = MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2,padding="same")(h)
h = Conv2D(4,(3,3),activation='relu',padding="same")(encoded)
h = UpSampling2D((2,2))(h)
outputs = Conv2D(1,(3,3),activation='relu',padding="same")(h)

model = Model(inputs=inputs, output=outputs)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
model.fit(X, X, batch_size=64, nb_epoch=5, validation_split=.33)
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected conv2d_3 to have shape (366, 930, 1) but got array with shape (365, 929, 1)
```

How can I solve this issue? How can I modify the CNN to take images with uneven dimensions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem lies in the UpSampling2D. You can pad the image with 0s unsymetrically and then crop the image to its original size, as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46938504/issues-training-cnn-with-prime-number-input-dimensions).
To help debugging you can use `print(model.Summary())` to check the dimensions of all layers.